# How do I create a list from a template and create all views with Powershell?

Tags: list, powershell, list-view

I am trying to imitate the process of creating a list from a template in the UI by using a Powershell script.  When you create a list from a template with the UI, all of the original list's views are created in the new list. But when I use:

```
$templateName = "CM-$listName"
$templateFilename = $templateName + ".stp"
$list.SaveAsTemplate($templateFilename, $templateName, "$listName template", $true)

...get the template copied to the list gallery of the $outWeb site collection ...

$listTemplates = $outRootWeb.Site.GetCustomListTemplates($outRootWeb)    
$newGuid = $outWeb.Lists.Add($list.Title, $list.Description, $listTemplates[$templateName])
```

I get the new list created but with only the **All Documents** view.

Comment: what kind of template you are using? OOTB or custom? which view were not being created via powershell

Comment: The template was created earlier in the same Powershell script using SPList.SaveAsTemplate.

Comment: I did find that the code that I was using (and I showed in the original question) was using the system-defined list templates and not my custom-created template.  So I fixed the code and guess what; I still get the list and no views!

Comment: Code now looks like:

`$listTemplates = $inWeb.Site.GetCustomListTemplates($inWeb)
$newGuid = $outWeb.Lists.Add($list.Title, $list.Description, $listTemplates[$templateName], $outWeb.DocTemplates[0])`

Answer (score 1):

Use [SPList.SaveAsTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.saveastemplate.aspx) for your source. Should be the same as the GUI.

If that doesn't work, access the [SPList.Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.views(v=office.15).aspx) collection and copy the views over to the new list after creating it from the template.

Comment: The template was created using SPList.SaveAsTemplate

Comment: Have you tried comparing the contents of the file  using SaveAsTemplate compared to the GUI file? I think they are both zip files. Also, could you update your code sample to include the save statement? It would also help to describe your custom document library. For example, what are the details of the views that don't reproduce?

Comment: I used my script to create the template and leave it in place.  When I create a library using the UI from this template, I get all views.  When I create another library  with a different name I see several differences:  1) The UI-restored library has all views created; the script one does not, 2) the UI-created library has content types in place; the script version does not 3) when you use View All Site Content the 2 libraries have different icons; the UI-created library has a normal-looking icon, but the script-created library has a lock instead of a white document in the lower right corner.

Comment: Just so you understand, now I am creating 2 lists from the same list template; 1 using the UI and 1 using my script.  The resulting lists are not the same.

Comment: Is it the same site in the site collection? Could it be a difference in the features active or permissions or lookup lists or something similar?

Comment: The list template is taken from another site collection in the same farm.  Both creations are being performed in the same site collection.

Comment: OK, now I have tried: 1) using a template created with the UI, 2) creating on the same site collection as the template was taken from, 3) the entire process on another farm.  Always the same results.

Comment: Have you tried it on the same site? Site collection is good. Site is better, for testing purposes.

Comment: Yes, my last experiments were on the same *exact* site.

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you running? I have seen issues with site templates before but it was on older versions of SharePoint.

Comment: SharePoint 2010 (Configuration database version: 14.0.6126.5000)

Comment: That's only two CU's from the most recent, so I would think most issues in 2010 should have been addressed

Answer (score 0):

Try this for creating list and view in sharepoint using powershell :

http://nkelkar.wordpress.com/2011/06/21/powershell-create-lists-add-columns-set-new-default-view/

Comment: Please add more details to your answer (e.g. give a summary of the info presented in the link you provided). Link only answers become less useful over time as links often break as time goes on.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered the solution to this problem.  If I add $outWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = $true before the $outWeb.Lists.Add() call, the list gets created correctly and completely.  I also set this property back to $false immediately after the list creation.